# How can I parse a string by mutliple delimiters using Java8 or regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a `List<String>` like this:

```
List.of(
  "ParamField(paramName=Thomas, paramValue=Admitted)",
  "ParamField(paramName=Martin, paramValue=Discarded)",
  "ParamField(paramName=Steve, paramValue=Admitted)"
);
```

How can I iterate the list and parse all string in such a way that at the end of iteration I can have a single string which contains something likes this

```
String s = "Thomas-Admitted;Marting-Discarded;Steve-Admitted";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Simple substring  and index of

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
      List.of(
            "ParamField(paramName=Thomas, paramValue=Admitted)",
            "ParamField(paramName=Martin, paramValue=Discarded)",
            "ParamField(paramName=Steve, paramValue=Admitted)"
    ).forEach(item->{
          list.add(item.substring(21,item.lastIndexOf(","))+"-"+item.substring(item.lastIndexOf("ue=")+3,item.lastIndexOf(")")));
    });
    String s =list.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

This is fairly easy to achieve with regex capturing groups. Your pattern will be `"ParamField\\(paramName=(.+), paramValue=(.+)\\)"` and then you simply match and get `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

Once you extracted that, simply create the string with a `StringJoiner` on `;` or similar.

Could look something like this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ParamField\\(paramName=(.+), paramValue=(.+)\\)");

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(";");
for (String paramField : paramFields) {
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(paramField);
  if (!matcher.find()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input format");
  }

  String name = matcher.group(1);
  String value = matcher.group(2);

  sj.add(name + "-" + value);
}

String result = sj.toString();
```

---

### With OOP

Ideally you would employ some OOP though and create a nice record `ParamField` with a factory method on that string and then use its getters. That way its easier to keep working with the data, in case you need to do more with it.

```java
record ParamField(String name, String value) {
  private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "ParamField\\(paramName=(.+), paramValue=(.+)\\)");

  static ParamField of(String line) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input format");
    }
    return new ParamField(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
  }
}
```

with a usage like

```java
List<ParamField> paramFields = lines.stream()
  .map(ParamField::of)
  .toList();
```

and then work with that data. For example build your string:

```java
String result = paramFields.stream()
  .map(paramField -> paramField.name() + "-" + paramField.value())
  .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

#### Enum

If you need to do more complex stuff with the data, I would suggest you go one step further and also put the **value** into an enum, such as:

```java
enum ParamValue {
  ADMITTED("Admitted"),
  DISCARDED("Discarded");

  // field, constructor, getter, of-method
}
```

so that you do not have to work with raw strings anymore but get all the type-safety Java can provide to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes with [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ParamField\\(paramName=(.+), paramValue=(.+)\\)");

var result = Stream.of(
                "ParamField(paramName=Thomas, paramValue=Admitted)",
                "ParamField(paramName=Martin, paramValue=Discarded)",
                "ParamField(paramName=Steve, paramValue=Admitted)"
        ).map(pattern::matcher)
        .filter(Matcher::find)
        .map(m -> String.format("%s-%s", m.group(1), m.group(2)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));

System.out.println(result);
```